# Passing dictionaries to __init__

Tags: python, dictionary

I am making a class in Python, and want to pass a dictionary as an argument to **init** and copy it to an instance variable. Something like this:

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self, dictionary): 
        self.copy = dictionary
```

But for some reason it is not passing the dictionary, maybe just its type? For instance when I try print(dictionary) in **init** it just prints "class 'dict'" instead of the actual dictionary. Not sure why this is happening, and I would greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: Can you add some context of using your class ?

Comment: The print is default behaviour. Look up pretty print: https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html

Comment: You didn't show us how you instantiate your class. Btw. you are not copying your class. You merely assign name `self.copy` to same dictionary as passed to your constructor. Changes to `dictionary`will propagate to `self.copy`.

Comment: `self.copy = dictionary` only stores a reference. If you really want a copy you must do `self.copy = dictionary.copy()`

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are not giving a dict instance in the constructor:

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self, dictionary): 
        self.copy = dictionary
        print(dictionary)

>>> f=foo({})
{}
>>> f=foo({'key': 'value'})
{'key': 'value'}
>>> f=foo(dict)
<type 'dict'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me

```
# foo.py

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, dictionary): 
        self.copy = dictionary
        print dictionary

dict_object = Foo({"mykey": "myvalue"})
```

Run it:

```
$ python foo.py
{'mykey': 'myvalue'}
```

Comment: `self.copy = dictionary` statement is useless in this case tho.